# Search string in comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

I'm trying to search a table of recipes that DON'T include any of the search terms in it's ingredients.  The ingredients of each recipe are stored in one field, separated by commas.

I've tried using WHERE NOT MATCH...AGAINST but that doesn't work in cases like when I search for Peas.  It will return results with pea protein in them.  I need to not have that.  This is also a problem with pluralization.

I tried using NOT REGEXP but I'm not too familiar with regular expressions and all the Googling I've done for the last two days hasn't produced a result.

Is there ANY way I can search this field in this table for multiple values and exclude them in the results?

Comment: i would have put the ingredients in a different table:
recipe<->recipe_ingredient<->ingredients

Comment: Or you could use `NOT FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: I've tried FIND_IN_SET to no avail.  It still runs into the problem of the Peas!  It's for an allergy DB, so if someone is allergic to Peas I can't have pea fiber, or pea protein in the results.  That's just one example

case1352 if I put the ingredients I'd still have the same problem no?  I'm not a pro at DB designs so if that's the better way to do it fine, but I still need to search against it

Comment: I'm starting to think my first approach is the best, WHERE NOT MATCH.  then I could just add to my PHP to include similar terms to search for and exclude?

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Comment: It's a simple table: id, name, ingredients with full text index on name and ingredients column

Comment: To re-iterate, when posting database related questions it helps to include an (ideally minimized) `CREATE` statement for the tables, the query you are working with, and expected inputs/outputs for much faster help. Keeping a junction table (`recipe_ingredient`) is helpful from a database design standpoint as it normalizes the data, which is much more supported for easy querying once you have a grasp on table `JOIN` operations. From there, you can also normalize related ingredients (e.g. `peas` can be associated with other ingredients in _another_ junction table, like `pea fiber`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the operators for the MATCH... AGAINST...

I think what you are looking for is:

```
WHERE MATCH(ingredients) AGAINST ("-pea*" in boolean mode)
```

Examples:

```
pea protein,radish
// not returned (as desired)

peas,beans
// not returned (as desired)
```

But there may still be issues:

```
peanut butter,bacon
// not returned (not as desired)

green pea soup,bacon
// returned (not as desired)
```

I'm sort of feeling like to do this 'right' you would need meta data on *each ingredient*.

Or alternatively you have allergen 'tags' that you apply to recipes -- separate from the ingredients themselves.

For instance if someone is allergic to 'gluten' that's not actually an ingredient at the recipe level.  It's a property of many recipe ingredients tho...

This approach would require you to compile a list of all known allergens and then apply them to the recipes, not sure of your context but allergen tagging could work as a folksonomy task.

Comment: I think you're right, I just need to keep playing with the operators.  I like your idea of tagging the recipe for certain allergens but unfortunately this has to be on the ingredient level for these patients.